# how to Export Video to youtube Php Script

Tags: php, youtube

I create Website that create video and video slideshow.
Now i want to add features Export Video to youtube.
How to do this.
I see servel site do this.
How they do this plz help me.
I have hostgator hosting and website

Comment: Yeah and now ? Should we do your work or what do you expect ? And what has this to do with Hostgator ? Hire a developer and pay him $500 a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By acheiving this, you need use the PHP Client Library with the YouTube API

Hope this link guide you about integration of Youtube API using php,

https://sites.google.com/site/poweredbyyoutube/youtube-data-api-via-php-displaying-and-uploading-videos

Guide here : https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php?csw=1#Uploading_Videos

Comment: ,Dear Sir i see it but can't get..

Comment: Give code that can i use